# Cannot exclude httpcomponents jar from Grails application

Tags: grails, dependencies, ivy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to work around [this issue](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws/issues/41) in my Grails application by excluding `httpclient-4.3.1.jar` and instead including `httpclient-4.3.2.jar`.

I have managed to include 4.3.2, but my problem is that I cannot really see why 4.3.1 is being included. I have run `grails dependency-report`, but this just shows version 4.1.2 being included in a few different plugins. 4.3.1 seems to be included at the 'root' level, like this:

```
...
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1
...
```

I have tried adding some `excludes` lines to the `dependencies` block in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
excludes 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1'
excludes 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1'
```

But I am unsure if this is even valid syntax. How can I exclude this version of the `httpclient` jar?

EDIT:

I have also tried adding an `excludes` for these dependencies to the `global` block in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1', 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1'
}
```

And also this:

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes 'httpcore:4.3.1', 'httpclient:4.3.1'
}
```

But this didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

"org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1" seems to be a default grails dependency, therefore it should be excluded in inherits("global") BuildConfig's block, not in dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. this didn't seem to work either. I've updated my question to show what I tried.